# Why is DISCARD ALL called many times in Azure PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, azure-postgres-database

I am debugging a high CPU load issue with Azure PostgreSQL flexible server. In the time window where CPU usage spikes I am seeing a lot of utility queries. They don't take long to process but there are hundred thousands of them.

[image]

The queries are all `DISCARD ALL` queries. What are those queries for and is it normal to see so much of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DISCARD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html) resets your database connection to "factory default".

I guess you're using some form of connection pooling. That's a good thing because opening a connection consumes a significant amount of CPU. However, before reusing a connection, it has to be reset, which is what DISCARD does.

The high number of DISCARDs is probably just a consequence of a high number of clients getting connections from the pool to do some work. So, a symptom of your issue, but not the cause.

If you're seeing a huge number of DISCARD's compared to other queries, then... maybe you have something that opens and closes a connection in a loop, or opens a connection every time it wants to do a query instead of keeping it open.